# Array remove parent arrays after json decode

Tags: php, arrays, json, session

I am working on a support system where a user can save his session in a database and a company can open his session on another computer to help him.

**My problem:**

The problem is that I have an extra level in my session array after decoding the json. (watch arrays below)

- So I need to remove that level (parent array) after.
- Or I need to save / import it another way.

**My functions:**

This function saves the session and json_encode's and saves it in a database row. Then it returns a "support url" which can be opened by the company to load the session.

```
function gtp_support_request( $referer ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $url_id         = url_to_postid( $referer );
    $request_id = time();
    $table      = $wpdb->prefix . 'support_requests';

    if( isset( $_SESSION ) ) 
        $config     = json_encode( $_SESSION );
    else 
        $config     = '';   

    $wpdb->insert( 
        $table,
        array(
            'request_id'        => $request_id,
            'config'            => $config,
            'url_id'            => $url_id,
        ),
        array( '%d', '%s', '%d' )
    );
    $request_url = get_permalink( $url_id ) . '?support_id=' . $request_id;
    echo $request_url;
}
```

This function gets the json data from the database by a support id from the URL and then json_decode's the config and loads it in the session.

```
function gtp_load_support_request() {
    global $wpdb;

    if( ! empty( $_GET['support_id'] ) ) {
        $request_id     = $_GET['support_id'];
        $table          = $wpdb->prefix . 'support_requests';
        $results        = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT config FROM $table WHERE request_id = $request_id" );
        $config         = json_decode( $results[0]->config, true );


        $_SESSION[]     = $config;
    }
}
```

**Before:**

```
Array
(
    [splashback] => Array
        (
            [dimensions] => Array
                (
                    [width] => 1200
                    [height] => 800
                )

            [hole] => Array
                (
                    [choice] => false
                )

            [holes] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [type] => Array
                                (
                                    [type] => single
                                    [name] => Single socket
                                )

                            [x] => 120
                            [y] => 300
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

**New array:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [splashback] => Array
                (
                    [dimensions] => Array
                        (
                            [width] => 1200
                            [height] => 800
                        )

                    [hole] => Array
                        (
                            [choice] => false
                        )

                    [holes] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [type] => Array
                                        (
                                            [type] => single
                                            [name] => Single socket
                                        )

                                    [x] => 120
                                    [y] => 300
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to do it like:

```
$_SESSION = $config;
```

Instead of:

```
$_SESSION[] = $config;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get around this by assigning not the whole result but the first element in it when restoring:

```
$_SESSION[]     = $config[0];
```

**EDIT**

`json_decode` returns an instance of `\stdClass` not an array. This means that you need to convert it to an array before you can access the keys like an array.

Try this:

```
$config = (array)json_decode( $results[0]->config, true );
$_SESSION[] = $config[0];
```

Comment: is it at the same place where you dump the content of `$config`?

Comment: Sorry I don't know what you exactly mean.

Comment: I mean where you got this dump of the new array that you included in your question? At that point the new array surely have a 0 index.

Comment: I placed a print_r( $_SESSION ); in the header of my website.

Comment: Try put it right after restoring it (`$_SESSION = $config`)